# Is there a better way of making sure that a coordinate is not out of range in an np.array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to make sure that when I iterate through coordinates (i, j) of a 2D np.array, and access "neighbors", that I am not accessing values that are out of the array's range. Is there a better way of doing it than what I do here?

I consider the following coordinates as neighbors:

- (i - 1, j),
- (i, j - 1),
- (i - 1, j - 1),
- (i - 1, j + 1)

```
import numpy as np

for (i, j), value in np.ndenumerate(arr):
    if i and j and i < arr.shape[0]:
        neighbors = [
            (i - 1, j),
            (i, j - 1),
            (i - 1, j - 1),
            (i - 1, j + 1),
        ]
        print(neighbors)
    elif i and j:
        neighbors = [
            (i - 1, j),
            (i, j - 1),
            (i - 1, j - 1),
        ]
    elif i:
        neighbors = [(i - 1, j)]
        print(neighbors)
    elif j and i < arr.shape[0]:
        neighbors = [
            (i - 1, j),
            (i, j - 1),
            (i - 1, j + 1),
        ]
        print(neighbors)
    elif j:
        neighbors = [
            (i - 1, j),
            (i, j - 1),
        ]
        print(neighbors)
    else:
        print("There are no neighbors")
```

Comment: Create a list of all neighbors of (i, j) using a list comprehension. Filter that list based on the bounds that the neighbors should be within.

Comment: Hi, can you develop on that? To put all neighbors in a list I can just do `neighbors = [(i - 1, j), (i, j - 1), (i - 1, j - 1), (i + 1, j - 1)]` but how should I filter it with a list comprehension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented something like this in the end:

```
import numpy as np

for (i, j), value in np.ndenumerate(arr):
    neighbors = [
        neighbor
        for neighbor in [(i - 1, j), (i, j - 1), (i - 1, j - 1), (i - 1, j + 1)]
        if neighbor[0] and neighbor[1] and neighbor[0] < arr.shape[0]
        ]
```

Inspired by [Bas van der Linden's coments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68256123/is-there-a-better-way-of-making-shure-that-a-coordinate-is-not-out-of-range-in-a#comment120633223_68256123).